# NullPointerException when loading an image from resource

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio

I copied an intel.png file to res/raw folder of my project. And I have the next code:

```
    @Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    imgCam = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);

    try {
        colorPattern = Utils.loadResource(this, R.raw.intel);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Imgproc.cvtColor(colorPattern, grayPattern, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
}
```

When I run the program I always get NullPointerException and the stack trace points to the Imgproc row.

What could be the problem?

Comment: You are not showing us where you initialized and declared `Imgproc`. Add that.

Comment: It is in the last row of onCameraViewStarted method which is in the MainActivity as the above code shows. The problem is that the colorPattern variable is null, but why the Utils.loadResource command doesn't work?

Comment: Why isn't that `cvtColor` inside the try block? This way if the `loadResource` fails, you just print a message and then happily proceed to use the uninitialized `colorPattern`...

Comment: OK. I put it inside the try block, but the problem is still the same. The loadResource() doesn't set a proper value.